# jQuery sum table toFixed not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum, calculated-columns

I have dynamic table with data that can be formatted differently. For example: 500  500,57 1500,00 1.500,00. 
Currently I'm doing str_replace to remove first dot on thousandth and then replace comma with dot.

```
echo str_replace(array(".", ",",), array("", "."), $row['rad_iznos']);
```

That works fine and I get only thousandth with dot separator on decimal numbers. However when I use 
toFixed(2) option on sum the value of decimal is left behind and it should work according to this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tofixed . 
As you can see only decimals after 2 digits are rounded up.

```
var totals=[0,0,0];
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var $dataRows=$("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

            $dataRows.each(function() {
                $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i){        
                    totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
                });
            });
            $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function(i){  
                $(this).html('<span style="font-weight: bold;">'+totals[i].toFixed(2)+' kn</span>');
            });

        });
```

You can see example here: [image]
.57 is missing and I just don't understand logic behind it. Please advise. thousandths value is correct.

Comment: parseFloat works :) The first suggestion is giving good decimals but wrong sum total of 6600 something... But I see now where the problem was, thank you for your help.

Comment: Alternatively: output the total row at the same time as you output the other rows and handle it in the back-end.

Comment: Thank you ill look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with `.toFixed()` but with:

```
totals[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
```

which will add each row's value as an integer - thus losing the decimal places as it goes, so when it gets to `.toFixed()` it's already lost the decimal places.

The solution is to use `parseFloat()` instead, to keep the decimal places:

```
totals[i] += parseFloat($(this).html());
```